# Everything under /dist folder is serving as index.html file in angular-cli 1.7 build

Tags: angular, laravel, docker, npm, angular-cli

I am using angular-cli with laravel 5.5

When I am opening my project it gives me following three errors:

> inline.bundle.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
>
> polyfills.bundle.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
>
> main.bundle.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

When I inspect those .js files, I found those are served as index.html. Not only js but every other file served as index.html and when it try to run js but finds HTM tags and throws error.

**nginx.conf**

```
> server {
>     server_name localhost;
>     index index.php index.html;
>     root /var/www/public;
> 
>     location / {
>         try_files $uri /index.php?$args;
>     }
> 
>     location ~ \.php$ {
>         fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
>         fastcgi_pass php:9000;
>         fastcgi_index index.php;
>         include fastcgi_params;
>         fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
>         fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
>     } }
> 
> server {    listen         80;    listen    [::]:80;    return        
> 301 https://$host$request_uri; }
```

Comment: How  did you configure your webserver?

Comment: I am setting this up in docker. Where laravel app (including angular) is connecting to nginx server pointing to localhost on port 8080.

Comment: Maybe show your nginx conf

Comment: I have added it in question itself.

Comment: It might be because nginx server couldn't serve static files.